# Python mask for 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have generated a mask in the following manner-

```
mask_v_co = numpy.ones((numRows_v_co, numCols_v_co)).astype(numpy.uint8)
counter = 0
for i in range(numRows_v_co):
 for j in range(numCols_v_co):
  if Data_v_co[i,j] < 0:
    counter += 1          # Counting missing observation
    mask_v_co[i,j] = 0
```

How can I generate a mask using numpy masked array module where 0 indicating invalid entries `(wherever Data_v_co[i,j] < 0)` and 1 to indicate valid entries?

Comment: It's help to find accurate answer if you give some input & output

Comment: Isn't that what you already did? What do you want to _do_ with that mask?

Comment: I want to do it in one line rather use two for loops as `Data_v_co` is a large array. I want to use this mask array containing only ones and zeros as input for kcluster in Pycluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just do something like the following?

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.ones_like(Data_v_co, dtype='int8')
mask[Data_v_co < 0] = 0

# count zeros
counter = np.prod(mask.shape) - mask.sum()
```